# Difference in using 'while not' & != in below code, using 'while not' executes code correctly as in type 2 below, with != its just a infinite loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, input, while-loop, operators

-----------------Type 1 begin----------------------

```
def player_input():

    marker = ''
    while (marker != 'X' or marker != 'O'):
        marker = input('please make a selection X or O').upper()

    if marker == 'X':
        return ('X' , 'O')
    else:
        return ('O' , 'X')
```

-----------------Type 1 end----------------------

-----------------Type 2 begin----------------------

```
def player_input():

    marker = ''
    while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
        marker = input('please make a selection X or O').upper()

    if marker == 'X':
        return ('X' , 'O')
    else:
        return ('O' , 'X')
```

-----------------Type 2 end----------------------

Comment: You have to use `and` instead of `or` in Type1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not the same logic. In the first definition, you’re testing if either

1. Input is not 0; or
2. Input is not X

One of these is always true, by definition. If the input is O it can’t be X, and vice versa.

The logic you intended to have is probably

```
while (marker != 'X' and marker != 'O'):
```